# Mingw - Remove option from spec file

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, mingw

When I call `gcc -v` on the command line I get `LDFLAGS=-s`. I want to remove this option as a default so that debugging information can be added properly.

Output of gcc -v command is below.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=f:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic 
--enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug 
--enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld 
--with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes 
--enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap 
LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I have tried to use the specs file, but I am not able to get which parameter should be changed to remove the above option.

The generated specs file by the command `gcc -dumpspecs > specs` is below.

```
*asm:


*asm_debug:
%{!g0:%{gstabs*:--gstabs}%{!gstabs*:%{g*:--gdwarf2}}} %{fdebug-prefix-map=*:--debug-prefix-map %*}

*asm_final:
%{gsplit-dwarf: 
       objcopy --extract-dwo     %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}      %{c:%{o*:%:replace-extension(%{o*:%*} .dwo)}%{!o*:%b.dwo}}%{!c:%b.dwo} 
       objcopy --strip-dwo   %{c:%{o*:%*}%{!o*:%b%O}}%{!c:%U%O}     }

*asm_options:
%{-target-help:%:print-asm-header()} %{v} %{w:-W} %{I*} %a %Y %{c:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %w%b%O}}%{!c:-o %d%w%u%O}

*invoke_as:
%{!fwpa:   %{fcompare-debug=*|fdump-final-insns=*:%:compare-debug-dump-opt()}   %{!S:-o %|.s |
 as %(asm_options) %m.s %A }  }

*cpp:
%{posix:-D_POSIX_SOURCE} %{mthreads:-D_MT} %{pthread:-D_REENTRANT} %{!no-pthread: } 

*cpp_options:
%(cpp_unique_options) %1 %{m*} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{f*} %{g*:%{!g0:%{g*} %{!fno-working-directory:-fworking-directory}}} %{O*} %{undef} %{save-temps*:-fpch-preprocess}

*cpp_debug_options:
%{d*}

*cpp_unique_options:
%{!Q:-quiet} %{nostdinc*} %{C} %{CC} %{v} %{I*&F*} %{P} %I %{MD:-MD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{MMD:-MMD %{!o:%b.d}%{o*:%.d%*}} %{M} %{MM} %{MF*} %{MG} %{MP} %{MQ*} %{MT*} %{!E:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!MT:%{!MQ:%{MD|MMD:%{o*:-MQ %*}}}}}}} %{remap} %{g3|ggdb3|gstabs3|gcoff3|gxcoff3|gvms3:-dD} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %{H} %C %{D*&U*&A*} %{i*} %Z %i %{fmudflap:-D_MUDFLAP -include mf-runtime.h} %{fmudflapth:-D_MUDFLAP -D_MUDFLAPTH -include mf-runtime.h} %{E|M|MM:%W{o*}}

*trad_capable_cpp:
cc1 -E %{traditional|traditional-cpp:-traditional-cpp}

*cc1:
%(cc1_cpu) 

*cc1_options:
%{pg:%{fomit-frame-pointer:%e-pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible}} %{!iplugindir*:%{fplugin*:%:find-plugindir()}} %1 %{!Q:-quiet} %{!dumpbase:-dumpbase %B} %{d*} %{m*} %{aux-info*} %{fcompare-debug-second:%:compare-debug-auxbase-opt(%b)}  %{!fcompare-debug-second:%{c|S:%{o*:-auxbase-strip %*}%{!o*:-auxbase %b}}}%{!c:%{!S:-auxbase %b}}  %{g*} %{O*} %{W*&pedantic*} %{w} %{std*&ansi&trigraphs} %{v:-version} %{pg:-p} %{p} %{f*} %{undef} %{Qn:-fno-ident} %{Qy:} %{-help:--help} %{-target-help:--target-help} %{-version:--version} %{-help=*:--help=%*} %{!fsyntax-only:%{S:%W{o*}%{!o*:-o %b.s}}} %{fsyntax-only:-o %j} %{-param*} %{fmudflap|fmudflapth:-fno-builtin -fno-merge-constants} %{coverage:-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage}

*cc1plus:


*link_gcc_c_sequence:
%G %L %G

*link_ssp:
%{fstack-protector|fstack-protector-all:-lssp_nonshared -lssp}

*endfile:
%{Ofast|ffast-math|funsafe-math-optimizations:crtfastmath.o%s}   crtend.o%s

*link:
%{mwindows:--subsystem windows}   %{mconsole:--subsystem console}   %{shared: %{mdll: %eshared and mdll are not compatible}}   %{shared: --shared} %{mdll:--dll}   %{static:-Bstatic} %{!static:-Bdynamic}   %{shared|mdll: -e _DllMainCRTStartup@12 --enable-auto-image-base}   %(shared_libgcc_undefs)

*lib:
%{pg:-lgmon} %{pthread:-lpthread} %{!no-pthread: } %{mwindows:-lgdi32 -lcomdlg32} -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32

*mfwrap:
 %{static: %{fmudflap|fmudflapth:  --wrap=malloc --wrap=free --wrap=calloc --wrap=realloc --wrap=mmap --wrap=mmap64 --wrap=munmap --wrap=alloca} %{fmudflapth: --wrap=pthread_create}} %{fmudflap|fmudflapth: --wrap=main}

*mflib:
%{fmudflap|fmudflapth: -export-dynamic}

*link_gomp:


*libgcc:
%{mthreads:-lmingwthrd} -lmingw32      %{static|static-libgcc:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}  %{!static:    %{!static-libgcc:      %{!shared:        %{!shared-libgcc:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}        %{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s -lgcc}       }      %{shared:-lgcc_s -lgcc}     }   }     -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt

*startfile:
%{shared|mdll:dllcrt2%O%s}   %{!shared:%{!mdll:crt2%O%s}} %{pg:gcrt2%O%s}   crtbegin.o%s

*cross_compile:
0

*version:
4.8.1

*multilib:
. ;

*multilib_defaults:


*multilib_extra:


*multilib_matches:


*multilib_exclusions:


*multilib_options:


*multilib_reuse:


*linker:
collect2

*linker_plugin_file:


*lto_wrapper:


*lto_gcc:


*link_libgcc:
%D

*md_exec_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix:


*md_startfile_prefix_1:


*startfile_prefix_spec:


*sysroot_spec:
--sysroot=%R

*sysroot_suffix_spec:


*sysroot_hdrs_suffix_spec:


*self_spec:


*cc1_cpu:
%{march=native:%>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch)   %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}} %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}

*shared_libgcc_undefs:
%{shared-libgcc: -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info}

*link_command:
%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:    %(linker) %{!fno-use-linker-plugin:%{flto|flto=*|fuse-linker-plugin:     -plugin %(linker_plugin_file)     -plugin-opt=%(lto_wrapper)     -plugin-opt=-fresolution=%u.res     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%:pass-through-libs(%(link_gcc_c_sequence))}}     }}%{flto|flto=*:%<fcompare-debug*}     %{flto} %{flto=*} %l %{pie:-pie} %{fuse-ld=*:-fuse-ld=%*}    %X %{o*} %{e*} %{N} %{n} %{r}    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{z} %{Z} %{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%S}}    %{static:} %{L*} %(mfwrap) %(link_libgcc) %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{fsanitize=address:}     %{fsanitize=thread:}}} %o    %{fopenmp|ftree-parallelize-loops=*:%:include(libgomp.spec)%(link_gomp)}    %{fgnu-tm:%:include(libitm.spec)%(link_itm)}    %(mflib)  %{fsplit-stack: --wrap=pthread_create}    %{fprofile-arcs|fprofile-generate*|coverage:-lgcov} %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{fsanitize=address:%{static-libasan:-Bstatic} -lasan %{static-libasan:-Bdynamic}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address}    %{fsanitize=thread:%e-fsanitize=address is incompatible with -fsanitize=thread}}    %{fsanitize=thread:%{static-libtsan:-Bstatic} -ltsan %{static-libtsan:-Bdynamic}    %{!pie:%{!shared:%e-fsanitize=thread linking must be done with -pie or -shared}}}}}     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}    %{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%E}} %{T*} }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `LDFLAGS=-s` only had effect when GCC *itself* was compiled. It is *not* passed to your linker when you *use* GCC to compile your program.

> I have tried to use the specs file, but I am not able to get which parameter should be changed to remove the above option.

Your `specs` doesn't contain the `-s`. There is nothing to remove (you are likely barking up the wrong tree).